# Is it possible to use AppSync and GraphQL without mapping templates?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-serverless

Is it possible to use AppSync and GraphQL without mapping templates? 
Because Serverless has a limit of 200 resources and every mapping template is new resource.

Thank you!

Comment: yes of course you can use other things that mapping templates , like Pipeline Resolvers or Unit Resolvers

Comment: But these will also add resources to serverless, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using serverless-appsync-plugin which didn't permit me to use the same GraphQL instance in multiple serverless projects.

I removed the plugin and referenced the API in different projects like this:

```
CreateUserDataSource:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::DataSource
    Properties:
      ApiId: { 'Fn::ImportValue': 'graphQLApiId-${self:provider.stage}' }
      Name: CreateUser
      Type: AWS_LAMBDA
      LambdaConfig: 
        LambdaFunctionArn: {'Fn::GetAtt': [CreateUserLambdaFunction, Arn]}
      ServiceRoleArn: { 'Fn::ImportValue': 'appSyncServiceRole-${self:provider.stage}' }

  CreateUserResolver:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::Resolver
    Properties:
      ApiId: { 'Fn::ImportValue': 'graphQLApiId-${self:provider.stage}' }
      DataSourceName: CreateUser
      FieldName: createUser
      TypeName: Mutation
      RequestMappingTemplate: "{
        \"version\": \"2017-02-28\",
        \"operation\": \"Invoke\",
        \"payload\": {
          \"field\": \"createUser\",
          \"arguments\": $utils.toJson($context.arguments),
          \"handle\": $utils.toJson($context.identity)
        }
      }"
      ResponseMappingTemplate: $util.toJson($context.result)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to use mapping templates. You’re correct about the 200 resource limit, but the limit comes from cloudformation which serverless uses under the hood. This limit can be somewhat mitigated by splitting different types of resources into different stacks (via a plugin).